# docker inside gitpod, to expose ports

Tags: docker, gitpod

from the terminal in a brand new repo (without gitpod.yaml file)

```
docker run -it -d -p 5000:5000  mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
docker exec -it dc84383888d9904d1a4581309a9284670cbcd589dc7d48239e31c5bebc60743b bash
dotnet new webapi -o TodoApi --no-https
cd TodoApi
dotnet watch run
```

the container seems correctly started without errors but the application is unreachable to the url: `https://black-shrew-sn7rpq5c.ws-eu18.gitpod.io:5000`
despite of  vs code ask me to make the port 5000 public!
Do i need to do something else to expose ports to the external world? like define ports in gitpod.yaml file? is possible to avoid it with some workaround?
i'm issueing these docker commands just to try, i dont' wanto to commit a gipod.yaml file to the repo